# Is it possible to create a new workbook that is not active?

Tags: excel, vba

Updated issue: The real issue seems to be my use of appending a date to the file name. I can't seem to reformat the date, and the error seems to be triggered by `/` in the date, so how can reformat this so excel understands that the date is included in the file name? I understand now that SaveCopyAs does not need a "dummy" file to upload to first.

I'm currently getting a runtime error 1004 for the method SaveCopyAs saying that it can't find the location of the new file I'm trying to create. I interpreted this to mean that I need to create a "dummy" file to hold the copied information before I overwrite it with the data and a new file name. Is this correct?

The solution would be simple to create the dummy file and refer to each file individually, and then continue as I interpreted above. However, I'm trying to loop this process and am using a module that is hosted in PERSONAL.XLSB so I cannot use `ThisWorkbook` and have to use `ActiveWorkbook`. My issue now is that I don't know how to create a automated process of copying the data to a new file because of my use of `ActiveWorkbook`.

This is my current code:

```
Sub cellvalue_filename()

    Dim Path
    Dim NewPath
    Dim WBname
    Dim Destination

    Path = "C:\oldfilelocation\"
    WBname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    NewPath = "C:\newfilelocation\"

    Destination = NewPath & Range("B2") & WBname

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs filename:=Destination
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you missing some `\\` in your paths?  It's not clearwhat the purpose of the `Source` path is?

Comment: I thought that originally, but they are correct.

Comment: So what value is in B2?

Comment: The value of B2 is a date, using the d-m-yyyy format

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/) in order to avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: So you really want to save a file to: `C:\newfilelocationd-m-yyyfilename.xlsx` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I included the last \ to the end: `C:\newfilelocation\`. Sorry about that, I should've been more clear in my code example.

Comment: Remember there's no way for us to tell what you have changed from your "real" code - that would be a common mistake to see in code here...  Remember you can always edit your question to fix problems which might lead others to suggest fixes which aren't needed. What's the exact error message you get?  Does the folder you're saving to already exist?  Also - `Quit` is a method of the `Application` - if you want to close a workbook then use   `ActiveWorkbook.Close`

Comment: Thank you, and I will be more clear in the future about making my code as similar to the real as possible. The error message I'm getting says it's runtime error 1004, and that is cannot locate my newfilelocation (the folder holding the new file is already created) because it either does not exist, is not the correct location, or is corrupted. I took that to mean that I needed a "dummy" file to host the incoming data and that `SaveCopyAs` does not create a new file on its own. I will also change the quit to close.

Comment: You do not need a "dummy" file in order to use `SaveCopyAs` - if you're getting an error message then most likely there is a problem with the path you're using.

Comment: Okay, maybe the dates are issue with the path.

Comment: `Range("B2")` should be `Range("B2").value`

Comment: Okay, I think I'm messing up at the date part when I check the value of B2 it comes back in a different format. So how can I make it stay in the d-m-yyyy format it is in the actual cell?

Comment: You can use `Range("B2").Text` instead of `Range("B2").Value` if you want it exactly as formatted in the cell.  Or if you know `Range("B2").Value` is a valid date, you can format it any way you want using `FormatDateTime`.

Comment: @Joe Thank you! It finally works!

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, it's better in VBA to refer explicitly to the workbook and worksheet you want, rather than relying on it being active.

You say you can't use `ThisWorkbook` because you are referencing a workbook other than the one that contains your VBA code, but that doesn't mean you have to use `ActiveWorkbook`.

Instead you can get a reference to a workbook when you open or create it, e.g.

```
Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
Set objWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(...)
...
objWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ...
```

Similarly using `Range("B2")` without specifying a Worksheet will assume the active worksheet in the active workbook.  Instead, explicitly specify the worksheet, e.g.:

```
Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1) ' or whatever worksheet you want 
...
Destination = NewPath & objWorksheet.Range("B2") & WBname
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses the question. The OP's code is in personal.xlsb, and appears to be intended to run on the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: @Comintern, personal.xslb contains macros that can work with any open workbook, not only the active workbook.

Comment: So for `Application.Workbooks.Open(...)` I'd have to use a specific file name?

Comment: I realize that. I was working on the assumption that "However, I'm trying to loop this process and am using a module that is hosted in PERSONAL.XLSB so I cannot use ThisWorkbook and have to use ActiveWorkbook" was intended to narrow the answer.